# Why does this DateTime usage not correctly account for "today"?

Tags: php, datetime

Why does this use of DateTime not correctly determine if the "classtime is today"? The result for 2017-11-19 is "classtime is in the past." Do I need to refernece the timezone from php.ini?

```
$class = new DateTime('2017-11-19'); 
$today = new DateTime('NOW'); 
if ($class > $today) {
    echo 'classtime is in the future', PHP_EOL;
} elseif ($class < $today) {
    echo 'classtime is in the past', PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'classtime is today', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Same result with this:

```
$class = new DateTime('2017-11-18'); 
$today = new DateTime('NOW'); 

$class->format('Y-m-d') < $today->format('Y-m-d');

if ($class > $today) {
    echo 'classtime is in the future', PHP_EOL;
} elseif ($class < $today) {
    echo 'classtime is in the past', PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'classtime is today', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Whats the timezone setting for the PHP?

Comment: i need it to use the timezone set in php.ini of the server.

Comment: is this database-related by any chance? If so, there may be an easier way to do this.

Comment: I do need to pull the value of $class from a database, but I haven't gotten to the point yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime uses the time also. So `$class` is `2017-11-19 00:00:00` and `$today` is a bit later, your local time with hour and all...

See also http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php in the example's area for more information.

Probably you will have to check like this:

```
$class->format('Y-m-d') < $today->format('Y-m-d');
```

use it like:

```
$class = new DateTime('2017-11-19');
$today = new DateTime('NOW');

$class_date = $class->format('Y-m-d');
$today_date = $today->format('Y-m-d');

if ($class_date > $today_date) {
    echo 'classtime is in the future', PHP_EOL;
} elseif ($class_date < $today_date) {
    echo 'classtime is in the past', PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'classtime is today', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I use that in my example?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Thanks, that works. Does this also respect the timezone set in the server's php.ini?

Comment: docs say: "If $timezone is omitted, the current timezone will be used." so you use both times the same timezone if you don't specify one